# Gstreamer: Strip out time offset part from time string

Tags: c, gstreamer

I use GstDateTime API to append time  to a file name. To convert time to a string, here is only gst_date_time_to_iso8601_string function that return string with time offset included:

```
2021-01-23T23:30:59+0100
```

I used this part of code to strip out time offset from time string:

```
g_autoptr (GstDateTime) date_time = NULL;
g_autofree gchar *time = NULL;
char *end;

date_time = gst_date_time_new_now_local_time ();
g_assert (date_time);

time = gst_date_time_to_iso8601_string (date_time);
/* strip out time offset from time string */
end = strrchr (time, '+');
if (end != NULL)
{
    *end = '\0';
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gst_date_time_to_g_date_time()` to get a [`GDateTime`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GDateTime.html) which will be much easier to work with. In your case, you can then use `g_date_time_format(gdatetime, "%F");` to only print out the date in the format you want.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the best way.

Comment: ah, I just took another look in your code, and if you want you can even skip GstDateTime altogether if you don't need it (by calling `g_date_time_new_now_local()`)